# mySql query to search data which content two number separately

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Data Example
1  P123456789a25t
2  15287536r25fas
3  25a123456789um
4  123456789p45ute
```

I would like to search data which content 123456789 and 45 separately.

I tried as "SELECT * FROM table WHERE data like '%123456789%' AND data like '45'"

```
Here I got the output as 
1  P123456789a25t
3  25a123456789um
4  123456789p45ute
```

But my required output is

```
4  123456789p45ute
```

which content both the number separately.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The requirement is not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE data like '%123456789%45%' OR data like
>   '%45%123456789%'